# transfer learning practice for distinguishing cat and dog

Tags: machine-learning, transfer-learning

i'm trying to practice transfer learning myself.

I'm trying to count the number of each cat and dog files (each 12500 pictures for cat and dog with the total of 25000 pictures).

Here is my code.[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Xxa.png)

And here is my path for the picture folder[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5A46.png).

I thought this was a simple code, but still couldn't figure out why i keep getting (0,0) in my coding (supposed to be (12500 cat files,12500 dog files)):(.

Comment: I believe you need another slash at the end of the `path`, after Transfer.

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of providing an image of your code. You could use a markdown code block with ```python your code ```.

Comment: **Note:** Also make sure that your files have a valid image format (jpg, png, etc). Currently it looks like their names are like `'cat.0'` (does that mean your image extension is '.0', or you have the file extension hidden?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.join()` inside `glob.glob()`. Also, if all your images are of a particular extension (say, **jpg**), you could replace `'*.*'` with `'*.jpg*'` for example.

### Solution

```py
import os, glob

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'train/*.*'))
```

As a matter of fact, you might as well just do the following using `os` library alone, since you are not selecting any particular file extension type.

```py
import os
files = os.listdir(os.path.join(path,'train'))
```

### Some Explanation

The method `os.path.join()` here helps you join multiple folders together to create a path. This will work whether you are on a Windows/Mac/Linux system. But, for windows the path-separator is **`\`** and for Mac/Linux it is **`/`**. So, not using `os.path.join()` could create an un-resolvable path for the OS. I would use `glob.glob` when I am interested in getting some specific types (extensions) of files. But `glob.glob(path)` requires a valid path to work with. In my solution, `os.path.join()` is creating that path from the path components and feeding it into `glob.glob()`.

For more clarity, I suggest you see documentation for [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html).

Also, see [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module for path manipulation as an alternative to `os.path.join()`.

Comment: Thank you! it worked! Could you tell me difference between glob.glob() and using os.path.join() inside glob.glob()??

Comment: @curtissohn Please consider **`accepting`** and **`upvoting`** the answer. Thank you.

Comment: `os.path.join()` helps you join multiple folders together to create a path. This will work whether you are on a Windows/Mac/Linux system. But as you know, for windows the path-separator is **\** and for Mac/Linux it is **/**, not using `os.path.join()` could create an un-resolvable path for the OS. I would use `glob.glob` when I am interested in getting some specific types of files. But `glob.glob(path)` requires a valid path to work with. In my solution, `os.path.join() is creating that path from the path components and feeding it into `glob.glob()`. For more clarity, I suggest you see docs.

Comment: @curtissohn Please **`accept`** the solution from the left end (there is a tick mark: when you click on that it would turn green). [How to **accept** an answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).